# Starup disc creator software freezing up

Tags: software-installation, software-center, software-sources

I bought Ubuntu 19.10 from Ebay on a dvd and installed it that way, but have been having numerous issues since then, such as my Brother MFC-L2703DW not working even after downloading driver installation tool from Brother for MFC-L2703DW. Brother finally called me up and asked me to install Teamviewer, which I attempted to do for debian 64 bit, but kept getting "file not supported" message", same thing for 32 bit. My desktop is 64 bit. Brother support suggested I reinstall Ubuntu 19.10 latest vesion, but again the usb stick I have (32 GB) gives me message "no permissions" when I try to download from ubuntu to the usb. Brother then said I should reinstall Ubuntu this time from web and try using usb.

I downloaded .iso from Ubuntu website onto my hard drive. Then I used Ubuntu's own Startup disc creator software to flash my usb stick. However after I changed the bios boot sequence to usb first then rebooted, the first screen showing "ubuntu" or "advanced options" etc appeared but would not let me change the highlighted portion or would not start the flash. It was completely frozen. I tried rebooted and did the whole process again and again - no luck.

I tried again on a different machine using Linux Mint - same thing - the startup disc creator software just freezes up.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu is one process, installing a network printer another... If your Ubuntu installation is working then your problem lies with Brother, no amount of reinstalling and re-creating boot disks is going to solve this for you... I have two Brother laserjets and I can tell you from my own experience that it takes some diddling to get them to work first time, also buying another printer is not likely to fix this problem, thought I would mention as much.
Welcome to Linux.